# Android camera and portrait rotation

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an issue in my Android App, I followed [this article](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) to take picture in my application and it works fine but unfortunately the picture is in landscape mode instead of portrait mode. I have found several posts on SO and also articles on the net concerning this issue, from what I understand this behavior is not Android behavior but device behavior, and it may change from a device to an other.

**So the question is :** when I get the picture from the intent, how do I know if the taken picture needs to be rotated or not?

Here you can see the capture taken with the emulator (I have same behavior on my Sony Xperia) :

[image]

And then when I display it in an ImageView :

[image]

Comment: Post your code where you showing this image we can rotate image programmatically

Comment: I already have the code to rotate the image, the question is how do I know if the picture actually need to be rotated

Comment: When you capture your image from front camera or back camera if you setting angle for single camera you need to rotate your image otherwise you need to set camera angle for front facing and back camera.

Comment: `the question is how do I know if the picture actually need to be rotated`. Examine the Exif header.

Comment: `when I get the picture from the intent,` You do not get it from an intent. Nor from the used camera app. The scenario is different. Please better describe what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't find any complete answer to my question, I post my solution.

**1. Get photo from the camera**

```
protected File pictureFromCamera;
protected Uri photoUri;
...
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
// Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
{
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    pictureFromCamera = generateFile();
    if (pictureFromCamera != null)
    {
        String authority = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider";
        photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(DermatoPhotoCollectionActivity.this, authority, pictureFromCamera);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_PHOTO_FROM_CAMERA);
    }
}
```

**2. Get orientation of the photo**

Here is the code to get the orientation, it is inspired by [this article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html). Be aware that this require a dependency :
`compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1"`

Getting the orientation of the photo depends of the device and might not work on some device (for example it works fine on my Xperia but not on Android Emulator).

```
public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri)
{
    InputStream in = null;
    int orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
    try
    {
        in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
        if (in != null)
        {
            android.support.media.ExifInterface exifInterface = new android.support.media.ExifInterface(in);
            orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(android.support.media.ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (in != null)
        {
            try
            {
                in.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return orientation;
}
```

**3. Rotate the picture if needed**

I use asyncTask to rotate the photo

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        final String pathPhotoFromCamera = pictureFromCamera.getAbsolutePath();

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = createProgressDialog();
        progressDialog.show();

        int orientation = getOrientation(this, photoUri);
        int rotationAngle = 0;

        if (orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL)
        {
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotationAngle = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotationAngle = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotationAngle = 270;
                    break;
            }
        }

        AsyncTaskRotatePicture.AsyncTaskParams params = new AsyncTaskRotatePicture.AsyncTaskParams(pathPhotoFromCamera, rotationAngle);

        AsyncTaskRotatePicture taskRotatePicture = new AsyncTaskRotatePicture(new CallBack()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute()
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        taskRotatePicture.execute(params);
    }
}
```

**4. Finally the code that rotate the photo**

The function overwrites the initial photo.

```
public static void rotatePhoto(String photoFilePath, int rotationAngle)
{
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFilePath);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle, (float) bm.getWidth() / 2, (float) bm.getHeight() / 2);
    byte[] extractedBitmap = extractByteFromBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth() - 1, bm.getHeight() - 1, matrix, true));
    saveBitmapOnSdcard(extractedBitmap, photoFilePath);
}
```

Comment: Hy there, can you please show how you did the `generateFile()`?

Comment: I have a custom function for that that matches my requirements, but the one given in linked article should work fine : https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en
Search for fonction : `private File createImageFile() throws IOException`